# Expo project TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.default.firestore')

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have and Expo project with this firebase config file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

if (!firebase.apps.length){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export { firebase };
```

I'm calling its methods like this:

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const evsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');

    const getEvents = () => {

        evsRef.onSnapshot(
            snapshot => {
                const evs = [];
                snapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                    const {name, height, features:{good, better, best}} = doc.data();
                    evs.push({
                        key: doc.id,
                        name, height, 
                        features:
                            {
                                good, 
                                better, 
                                best
                            }
                    }) 
                })
                setEvents(evs);
            }
        )
        return;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getEvents();
        console.log('Testing: ', events);
    },[events])
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.default.firestore')
```

Any ideas? I'm new to React-Native/Expo and I can't find any consisting examples as to what method to use for communication with firebase/firestore, so far I've been using collection(db, 'collection name') but this one seems more documented.

Comment: It's _really_ bad practice to share the apiKey. You should probably generate a new one if that was a production key, or attached to an account that has billing details filled out.

Comment: What version of Firebase do you have installed? I suspect that you have Firebase@9.x, but your code is for Firebase@8.x and lower.

Comment: I'm using version 9.9.2

Comment: Do you need the `/compat/` versions that you're importing? I had a lot of trouble with those in general.

Comment: As you pointed out, I was using V8 code with V9 so I solved it by just adjusting the code, I will post the answer later, as it also has to do with me misinterpreting the documentation. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Can you provide the answer so anyone can benefit from it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mixing up V9 with code from V8 as it was pointe out in the comments, the confusion started with me using the node.js examples as opposed to Web 9 examples, so be aware of that. Here's the code:

Firebase Config

```
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import geofire from 'geofire';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);

export default firestore;
```

And this is the query code:

```
const getEvents = async (dbx) => {
    const eventsCol = collection(dbx, 'testing');
    const eventSnapshot = await getDocs(eventsCol);
    const eventList = eventSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
      ({
        ...doc.data(),
        key: doc.id
      })
    );
    setEvents(eventList)
    return eventList;
  }
```